# How to clear editText of the list(not listView or recyclerView) items

Tags: android, list, android-edittext, android-adapter

The list I'm using here is not the RecyclerView or ListView. It is crated using just linearLayout.

```
llItemList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_list);
```

And adding `views` like below

```
listAdapter = new ReadingSheetAdapter(ReadingSheetActivity.this, readingDataList);
for (int i = 0; i < arrPdtId.size(); i++) {
     llItemList.addView(listAdapter.getView(i, null, llItemList));
}
```

Here, I'm using `editText` in the list items, which is described in adapter class.
I'm having a `button` in the activity.

I want to clear all `editText` value as the button is clicked.

Below is `getView()` of the `ReadingSheetAdapter` class.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reading_sheet_layout, parent, false);

            holder.pdtName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_pdt_supp);
            holder.keyId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.key_set);
            holder.tvOpenRead = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.open_val_set);
            holder.etClosRead = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.clos_val_set);
            holder.consumption = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.consumption_val);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        ReadingData temp = readingList.get(position);
        holder.pdtName.setText(temp.pdtName);
        holder.keyId.setText("Key "+temp.keyId);
        holder.tvOpenRead.setText(temp.closReading);
        holder.holdPos = position;

        holder.etClosRead.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean ignore = false;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (ignore)
                    return;
                ignore = true;
                valOpenReading = holder.tvOpenRead.getText().toString();
                arrValOpenRead[position] = valOpenReading;
                valClosReading = s.toString().equals("") ? "0": s.toString();
                arrValClosRead[position] = valClosReading;
                if (Integer.parseInt(valClosReading) < Integer.parseInt(valOpenReading)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Check once! closing reading should be more than opening reading!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    valConsumption = "0";
                    holder.consumption.setText("");
                } else {
                    valConsumption = (Integer.parseInt(valClosReading) - Integer.parseInt(valOpenReading))+"";
                    arrValConsumption[position] = valConsumption;
                    holder.consumption.setText(valConsumption);
                }
                ignore = false;
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

How can I perform action on `editText` which is in adapter class as the button is clicked which is in activity?

Thanks.

Comment: `down-voters` are welcome here. But pls help me out here first.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your have a collection of objects:

> readingList

you should iterate over that collection and empty the strings you want to remove, that will erase the text data in your adapter.

then all you have to do is updating:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the button is in `Activity`, how can I pass the object of button in adapter? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: you don't need to pass the button in order to achieve this solution, but if you want you can use dependency injection to adapter

Comment: I'm not using recyclerView or listView here. I've updated the questions Pls have a look.

Comment: dependecy injection has nothing to do with recyclerView/ListView. you can just pass your button as parameter to your adapter

Answer (score 0):

either using `notifyDataSetChanged()` (if effects whole adapter) or `notifyItemChanged(position)` - (it effect specific position of adapter).

Comment: I'm not using recyclerView or listView here. I've updated the questions Pls have a look.